# How to change text at the top of your Android-app?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

[image: The text NWZC 2016]

I wanna change like you see in the picture above the text **NWZC 2016** at the top of my app, it's the title of my app. I have 5 different activities, and in every activity I want some other text and not this "NWZC 2016". How can I do that?

I've looked in the files styles.xml and strings.xml and AndroidManifest.xml for trying things. I couldn't find anything clear on the Internet.
Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Touch the blue text "The text NWZC 2016" for a (maybe) helpfull picture

Comment: What value does your strings.xml `app_name` resource have? Also, what does the `android:label` attribute of the Activity in your Manifest.xml say?

Answer (score 2):

In code (call it in onCreate of Activity):

```
setTitle("Your title here");
```

In Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity"
    android:label="Your title here" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Basically the same thing I said before :/

Comment: Our answers only differ in 1 minute, so I didn't see your answer before I wrote this :)

Answer (score 1):

In your Manifest file:

```
       <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Change the `label` to anything you want. Add the `string` resource you want shown to `strings.xml` and reference it here. If you wish no title, delete the `label` or simply make your activity be without the action bar.

Answer (score 0):

**#** If your `Activity` extends from `AppCompatActivity`, then you can `programmatically` change actionbar `Title` using `getSupportActionBar().setTitle()` method;

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ............
        .................. 
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hello Android");
    }
}
```

**#** If your `Activity` extends from `Activity`, then you can `programmatically` change actionbar `Title` using `getActionBar().setTitle()` method;

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ............
        .................. 
        getActionBar().setTitle("Hello Android");
    }
}
```

**OR**

You can define a fixed `title` from `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:label="Hello Android"> <!-- Better to use string from res/strings.xml -->
```

Hope this will help~